# Build Beam pipelines using Bazel (with DataflowRunner)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bazel

I use Bazel to build my Beam pipeline. The pipeline works well using the DirectRunner, however, I have some trouble managing dependencies when I use DataflowRunner, Python can not find local dependencies (e.g. generated by `py_library`) in DataflowRunner. Is there any way to hint Dataflow to use the python binary (`py_binray` zip file) in the worker container to resolve the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) for more details on setting up dependencies for Python SDK on Dataflow. If you are using a local dependency, you should probably look into developing a Python package and using the `extra_package` option or developing a custom container.